# Maven deployments and git branching hell

Tags: git, maven

I am working on a single page app and at some point we decided to do a rebranding ( new skins and features) and we took the decision to re-architect our css, which made us change our html and js. We were supposed to merge the new branch back to master as soon as possible, but now for some marketing issues, it has to be postponed for another six months. If we merge back to master the previous skin will be broken which means we cannot deploy any fixes to live...We constantly merging from master to keep the new branch up to date but this cannot continue for another six months...

One idea is to change the version of the branch from 1.x.x to 2.x.x and be able to start create release branches and tags from the branch cause we want to start deploying to private betas etc. Which leaves us with a master at 1.x.x and a branch at 2.x.x

The other solution could be to port the old theme to the new css architecture, in order to be able to merge back to master, which will take long time...

Is there any other way to solve a problem like that? Could you see other problems with the first approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I see a problem.  You have two versions of the application that live in different branches.  Why wouldn't one want to just release the beta from the branch that the beta is being developed on (treat it as a "master" branch of sorts)?

Comment: If you use Jenkins or similar tool: Create a Jenkins job that tries to merge master to the new branch on every commit to the master branch. Don't push the actual merge result anywhere. But have the job fail if the merge fails, indicating someone should do a manual merge. This way you'll only have to do merges (during the next six months) when there is actually some conflicts. And yet be saved from constantly merging or doing one megamerge half a year later..

Comment: @Makoto I forgot to mention that our QAs are pressing us to be able to deploy tagged versions of the new branch cause they want something stable and reproducible to raise bugs against

Comment: @JonasBerlin yes we use Jenkins, this is a good idea thnx

Comment: @Makoto Additionally 90% of the code is the same as the current master. If we bump the version of the branch to 2.x.x do you see an problems with merging from the master?

Comment: You can still tag it like you would any other commit.  It'd be best to differentiate the source of the tag though (include the name of the branch).  I'm still not sure I see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Since the far-fetched Jenkins option turned viable, I converted my comment to an answer.*

Create a Jenkins job that tries to merge master to the new branch on every commit to the master branch. Don't push the actual merge result anywhere. But have the job fail if the merge fails, indicating someone should do a manual merge. This way you'll only have to do merges (during the next six months) when there is actually some conflicts. And yet be saved from constantly merging or doing one megamerge half a year later..